# How should I name a java.util.Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, naming-conventions

I have a `java.util.Map` that maps from a logical name to a set of parameters to use with that name.

```
Map<String,Parameters> howShouldINameThee = ...;
```

What is the best name for this map?

Should I go simple and just call this `parameters` or `parametersMap`?

Do I include information about the key in the name like `paramtersByName` so that how to use the `String` key is more obvious?

Answer (score 122):

A Map maps something **to** something else.
I like to use names like `uidToPerson`. "To" being the shortest unambiguous way I can think of to show that I have a map.

Edit:
I'll add that I prefer to have the map named this way, because "key" and "value" appear in that order in the name. As opposed to `valueByKey`. In mapping operations, the key comes first. You `put(key, value)` or `get(key)` that gives a value.

Of course this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I use this convention, but I'm unsure how to map a Map of Maps...

Comment: @CarlPritchett quite unusual to me, but what about fooToBarToBaz? Or bazByBarByFoo...

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni So is that a fooToBar -> Baz or foo -> BarToBaz? Still ambiguous...

Comment: @CarlPritchett if you regularly use hashmaps as keys then, yes, this will be a problem. I have never done this or seen it done in 20 years of coding. If it happens I'll have to use a different convention.

Comment: @z5h true! But I was more thinking of how easy it was to read. I agree that a new name would be better.

Comment: I almost use this convention, too. But I tend to write it this way: key2value. This way you will instantly see that this variable is a mapping.

Comment: Isn't `fooToBar -> Baz` and `foo -> BarToBaz` a same thing? It's effectively `Map<Foo, Map<Bar, Baz>>` in any case, no?

Answer (score 42):

I tend toward something like `parametersByName` to leave no confusion about what the contents of the `Map` are.  You never know when you're going to have to revisit code that you haven't looked at in a long time.

In Java, I find it unnecessary to include the name of the data structure (like `parametersByNameMap`) since the typing is explicit.

Comment: Your last sentence is correct for Maps, but not necessarily for Lists, Sets, etc.

Comment: It is generally considered a bad practice to pollute names with data types. It's redundant, does not play well with refactorings and hurts readability by lengthening names.

Answer (score 17):

You actually answer the question yourself.

> What is the best name for this map?

You want to map your map to a name, so you say 'name for map' !!

That should be the naming convention, in my opinion: *valueForKey*.

With the other suggestions keyToValue and valueByKey, I feel you need to add the word Map at the end, like this: keyToValueMap, valueByKeyMap. When you use *For* it's apparent from the language that it is a mapping.

Comment: IMO, placing the value first (whether in valueForKey or valueByKey) makes the type you're retrieving more obvious. As valueForKey.get(key) gives the value, which is the first thing I read when scanning.

Comment: I don't see how valueForKey is any different than valueByKey in regards to needing Map at the end (I don't think Map is needed, but is obvious by the name)

Answer (score 1):

In my apps there would be quite many types of parameters.

For example, in GAE, when I need to extract the http request parameters into a serializable form, I name the map httpRequestParameters or httpReqParams. sessionAttrs, for example.

For GWT RPC, client-to-server parameter hash, I would name it client2ServerParams or clnt2SrvrParms and name the counterpart server2clientParams or srvr2ClntParms.

In openid consumer, I would name the map, consumerAuthRequests or redirectFormParameters and its counterpart providerResponses.

In the map of reformatted input Main arguments, I would call it inputArgs.

In my cases, httpRequestParametersBy name, client2ServerParamsByName, consumerAuthRequestsByName, inputArgsByName, or inputArgValueByKey,  etc  would be redundant and too long because I would always know that the key of the map is a "name" anyway. I just make sure the name is plural to give me an inkling that it is a collection.

Exception to this practice is when the key is not a name but an object than I would name the map like vehicleByDriver, projByMgr, toxicFoodListByAnimal.