# How to name a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

This might be a silly question, but I have never found a satisfying way to name a variable of type `HashMap<K,V>` in Java. For example - lets say I have a `HashMap` where every bucket is a `<K,V>` pair where `K` is a `String` say representing "State" and `V` is an `Integer` representing the number of counties the state has.

Should the `HashMap` be named as "`mapStateCounty`", "`stateToCountyMap`", etc. ?
Which one seems logically more appealing and intuitive to understand without sounding confusing and verbose?

Comment: “There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things”

Comment: ...and off-by-one errors.

Comment: also, add de-referencing de-allocated memory, you never know when it will crash.

Comment: You can name it as countiesInState

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I name a java.util.Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253453/how-should-i-name-a-java-util-map)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I like this question because Java does not allow map access via an operator like `[]`.  In other languages we could say things like

```
numberOfCountiesIn["HI"]
```

or

```
countyCountOf["CA"]
```

or

```
numCountiesIn->{"MA"}
```

or (in Scala, this is cool)

```
numCountiesIn("WA")
```

and on and on.  None of these work in Java, because of that silly `get` word!

```
countyCounts.get("NY")
```

Indeed!

EDIT: I actually think `countyCounts` is the *best* answer (IMHO); I was just making the point that the need for `get` limits one's choices.

Comment: I think `CountryCounts` would lead to the assumption that the variable contains a simple Collection like a List but not a Map. How would you distinguish between them?

Comment: Nice observation! When `countyCounts` is used by itself, I'd grant the ambiguity. But when used in context with a `get`, and in `countyCounts.get("NY")` to me, at least, we know we are getting the count _for_ `NY` so it is a map, while if we saw `countyCounts[3]` it's an array, and `countyCounts.get(3)` is a Java list. Personally I am willing to put up with that ambiguity, but I agree it is a matter of preference. That silly `get` makes it awkward (in English anyway)! The flexibility you get in other languages allows `countyCountsFor[state]`, `countyCountOf`, `countiesIn`, etc. is so nice!

Comment: I think there would be some value in specifying the nature of the keyset with a name such as `countyCountsByState`

Answer (score 49):

I don't believe there is a hard-written rule anywhere that tells you how to name your map, so as long as you come up with a rule that makes sense to you (and your teammates), then it should be fine.

Personally, I like to call my maps `keyToValue` or `valueByKey`.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly avoid putting implementation details in the name of a variable, e.g. `StateToCountyMap`. Today you are using a `Map` interface but tomorrow you can decide to store your data in another type and the name of your variable has to be refactored otherwise it will become invalid and misleading.

Your data represents association of a state to its number of counties, so my advice is to name the variable as `stateToNumberOfCounties`. The key point in this name is `to` which designates that this variable stores an association, the part before that is the `key` and the part after is the `value` or `values` that are associated to the corresponding `key`. Also it would be indistinct to name the variable as `stateToCountyNumber` because one could not tell if it stores relation between a state and its number of counties or it stores a single number that represents the number of state to county associations, thus you would have to go back and forth in your code to check if it is of type `Map` or of type `int`.

Comment: `Map` is not always an implementation detail, though, as sometimes what you want is really a map from A to B.

Answer (score 10):

I found a great case for `countiesByState` [here](http://softwareas.com/naming-conventions-for-key-value-maps/):

> `valuesByKeys`, as in teamsByCaptains. If you're going to include both key and value, this seems to read best. At a high level, you can read it as just "teams", so anything that's performed on it is being performed on teams. The "byCaptains" prefix reads as it should do: a less significant qualifier that follows the teams around to help someone understand the structure if they need to.

This also allows you to access a value in a JSP with the nice notation `countiesByState[myState]`.

Answer (score 9):

I would call it `numCounties` or `countyCounts`.

Comment: I sometimes name maps as if they were functions taking K as a parameter and returning V. That convention leads to names like the ones in this answer.

Comment: I think this would lead to the assumption that the variable contains a simple Collection like a List but not a Map.

Comment: I would think `numCounties` creates the assumption that the variable holds an _integer_, but I would guess, and this is heavily qualified by personal bias and experience, that `countyCounts` would generally invoke the idea of a map as opposed to a collection. But I will warrant that we are all different and it is difficult to please everyone. If Java did not require access with `get` there are better alternatives. Of course you could put the word `map` in the variable name, too :) Gotta love programming because there is rarely every a right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever explains it best - In this case `stateToCountyMap` is ok or else `countiesInStateMap` can be used.

Comment: there's definitely a widely-accepted convention to name variables in camel case though...

Comment: I am still ok with camel case as long as I  don't have a mountain range!

Answer (score 1):

I would call it **mapStatesbyCountyCount**, then again its bit lengthy variable name...

Comment: Hey, not even the Hungarians use hungarian notation anymore! ;)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be to have it `countiesCountOfStateMap` or simply `countiesOfStateMap` since we will be getting the counties count using the State.

It would be more meaningful to have it like this, so when new person looks into your code atleast he would be aware of what is contained in it.

But at the end of the day its your decision to have the appropriate name and as @tulskiy mentioned naming the class and variable appropriately is one of the harder things.

Answer (score 0):

`stateToCountyNumber`. More generally, `keyToValue` for any map.

This naming rule is deeply rooted in the essence of a map — a map is a function in disguise. A map transforms a key to the corresponding value. Who also does the transformation work? Functions! `toString`, `toDouble`, to name a few. So I believe a map variable should be named in the same way functions are named.

Answer (score -1):

Storing states and counties in that variable it would be confusing to name it map - call it `stateCountyHash` or `numCountiesByState`

Comment: “it would be confusing to name it map” – why? That’s what it does: it *maps* values from an input to an output domain. “hash”, on the other hand, is a particularly bad name since it’s describing an irrelevant (and maybe even wrong – what if the type of the map is subsequently changed to `TreeMap`?) implementation detail rather than the usage of the variable.

Comment: Does the *map* from the name reffers to a data structure or to the representation of geographical landscape? - in this context is confusing :)

Comment: In mathematics, [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29) describes pretty exactly what a `Map` in Java, or more generally a [map in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) does. The context (e.g. if the variable is called `mapStateToCountyCount`) should make it clear that its meaning in geography is irrelevant here.

Comment: mapStateToCountyCount does seem very reasonable, and it also leaves out the detailed implementation semantics such as whether it is referring to a - TreeMap or LinkedHashMap. Though map, county, state (all in one variable) might be tad confusing to someone coming from Geography/History background!