# How to name a function that returns a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I know [How to name a HashMap in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659455/how-to-name-a-hashmap-in-java), but what is the best name for the function that does the work of building and assigning the keys? A function that returns `Map<State, County> countiesByState` could be named

```
sortToState(myCounties)
mapByState(myCounties)
getCountiesByStateMap(myCounties)
getCountiesByState(myCounties)
getMapByState(myCounties)
```

Comment: What does the method do? Is it just a getter method? Also, what does the containing class do and how client code should be using the method?

Comment: It's doing complicated stuff like sorting the items into buckets or deciding which fee code a transaction belongs under. The map does not exist yet, we are creating it. Containing class might just want everything sorted out so it can print a report.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Comment: I appreciate that someone on this site still recognizes questions about  best practices have real answers even if there is some opinion to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To a certain degree, this is about *style*. Therefore you should rather ask the people working on this code base about what they consider the *best* name in your project. It doesn't matter what the "global best practice" is here, what matters is *what works best for you*!

Nonetheless, the *clear* winner is `getCountiesByState(myCounties)`:

- there is no need to *specify* the collection type anywhere (`fooByBar` already tells us that this is about a mapping!)
- and `sortToState()` is a bit misleading, as it is *not* making clear that it will return a map!

As that *sorting* aspect seems to be important, why not `getSortedCountiesByState(myCounties)` or `getCountiesSortedByState(myCounties)` or getCountiesBySortedStates(myCounties)` ...

Comment: `sortToState` is what prompted me to make the question, as it sounds to me like it should return a sorted TreeMap. It's a non-native speaker just trying to assign things into buckets, like you would sort out coins by quarter, dime, nickel. Not producing anything ordered by their value or anything like that.

Comment: See my updates. The question is rather: is sorting a byproduct, or *the one essential* property of your collection?! That is for you to decide!